# Is T(x) considered a cast?

Tags: c++, casting

The following is a cast:

```
int foo = (int) somefloat;
```

However, is this considered a cast?

```
int foo = int( somefloat );
```

More importantly, if there is a difference between the two, is the resulting compiled code different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example is often called a function style cast and was added to C++ but there's no difference between the two in terms of semantics/object code.

Here's a good explanation of the reason that function style casts were added:

[What exactly is or was the purpose of C++ function-style casts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474933/what-exactly-is-or-was-the-purpose-of-c-function-style-casts)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference of result, however only first example can be used in C. In C++ you can use both.

Comment: Would the second still be considered a C-style cast?

Comment: @MarkP Yes, it's still a C-style cast with all of its disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is also a cast. C++ enables this style of casting, C only has `(type)expression` format casts. They're equivalent.