# What's the difference between static cast and the other one in the example

Tags: c++, casting

```
hours = static_cast<double>(minutes)/ 60
```

and

```
double minutes
hours = int (minutes)/ 60
```

1. is constrained casts? correct me if i'm wrong

whats the second one called? and whats the difference if they both will produce the same result?

if then which is better to use?

Comment: Well the second is *undefined behavior* since you don't initialize or assign to `minutes`. Don't know about the first. And there's no way of telling if both will produce the same result with the information you give us, especially since the conversions are to different types.  Please create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: And if you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Well, at least one is to `double`, and the other is to `int`, here's the difference. If you use the same type, there's no difference in this case. In general, there's no (or negligible) difference when the target type isn't a pointer nor a reference. If they are, the second form allows some sloppy casts, and the first doesn't, so the second form shouldn't generally be used to cast to pointers and references. It's fine otherwise, though some people take a radical "second form bad" stance.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is or was the purpose of C++ function-style casts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4474933/509868)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

`int (minutes)` is called "function cast" or "functional-style cast", because it looks like a function call. It does the same as C-style cast `(int)minutes` — truncates `double` to `int`. The difference between this and `static_cast` is only in syntax: the latter is more verbose, so easier to search for in code.

`static_cast` is different from C-style cast in type-safety — it fails to do suspicious conversions (e.g. integer to pointer). Other than that, it's identical.

---

Semantics:

```
hours = static_cast<double>(minutes)/ 60
```

This does floating-point division, generating a floating-point result. If `hours` has floating-point type (e.g. `double`), it will retain fractional part (e.g. 10 minutes is 0.16666666666666666 hours).

If `hours` has integer type, the compiler will generate type conversion from `double` to `int` (and probably a warning) and truncate the number of hours. This is bad code, because it hides some of your calculation logic behind obscure language rules. If you want to convert from `double` to `int`, do it explicitly using `static_cast` or C-style cast.

```
double minutes;
hours = int (minutes)/ 60
```

This truncates minutes to integer and calculates an integer number of hours from that. A bit surprising that `minutes` can hold non-integer values but `hours` cannot, so you might want to explain your calculation logic in a comment.

Comment: Oh I see thank you so much, you really explained it very well.